# Categories during the Webpart Selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

is it possible to create categories during the webpart selection, in the modern experience, except developing them on my own? I want to create a category which is relevant to the users and simplify the experience. I would like to add the default webparts to it.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. It's designed by Microsoft by default.

Comment: This is what i thought. I just wanted to get sure.